# Timer value finishes before the progress bar start

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I'm trying to login using my login form.I have a button, a timer control and a progress bar control. On form load my progress bar control's visibility set to false.

Here's my code for the button login.

```
  SqlDataReader reader = new loginUserOP().userLogin(txtUserID.Text, txtpwd.Text);
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    myPbar01.Visible = true;
                    myTimer01.Enabled = true;
                    LoggedUserInfo.lguserfname = (String)reader[0];

                }
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                reader.Close();
                //MessageBox.Show("Logged in as " + LoggedUserInfo.lguserfname + "\n user ID is :" + LoggedUserInfo.lguserid);

            }
            else
            {
                myTimer01.Enabled = false;
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password \n Please enter a valid userid and a password. ", "Incorrect Credentials");
                txtUserID.Text = "";
                txtpwd.Text = "";
            }
```

And this is my code for timer tick event.

```
    private void myTimer01_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myPbar01.Value = Convert.ToInt32(myPbar01.Value) + 10;
            if(Convert.ToInt32(myPbar01.Value)==100)
            {
                myTimer01.Stop();

                txtUserID.Text = "";
                txtpwd.Text = "";   
            }   
    }
```

And here's how I open frmMain when login is successful.
This is the code of my Program.cs file.

```
  [STAThread]
  static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        using (var login = new frmLogin())
        {
            if (login.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
        }

        Application.Run(new frmMainAdmin()); 
   }
```

In my timer properties I have set Enabled to true and interval to 1000.

The problem what I'm having is, some times when I start to enter user name and password, after entering username, while I'm entering password my username and password get cleared and it closes login form before the progress bar finishes and even before it appears. How to solve this? what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't understand which is the purpose of a progressbar here

Comment: @fillobotto I want to show some thing before it directly open frmMain. So I want to show a progress bar load and then the main to be opened.

Comment: Did you use the debugger? Set any breakpoints? Does it hit breakpoints which it shouldn't? Where goes it wrong?

Comment: may be you are hitting enter key after typing username.. If your login button code resides inside button press event nothing seems to be wrong

Comment: @KCdod No i pressed the tab. Yes it is inside button press. The main problem is when I type the user name and password for the first time, after sometime the controls are getting cleared. But after that it does not happen. For the second time you can type normall without getting deleted.